# Как получить время соединения http запроса в c sharp?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, http

Задача стоит получить время соединения с сервером, не время запроса целиком а именно время соединения, без времени передачи данных, ожидания ответа и прочего.

Хорошо бы с примером кода) Но и ссылки полезные пойдут.

Comment: ну как вариант синхронизировать время сервера и клиента, затем перед вызовом метода записать в переменную date1 текущую дату,  на сервере в вызываемом методе записывать в возвращаемую переменную текущее время сервера. Потом от даты сервера отнять первую дату

Comment: Все бы ничего, но сервер то не мой)

Comment: Тогда зачем это нужно?

Comment: Мне необходимо получить пинг от меня до сервера через проксю(Ping с проксями не работает), а значит нужно запросить любую страницу через проксю и получить время ожидания соединения, без коммутаций и ожидания ответа.

Comment: [вот](https://www.wormly.com/test-remote-ping) это может помочь

Comment: взято [отсюда](https://superuser.com/questions/175428/how-to-ping-when-behind-a-proxy)